# Cannot edit own my own .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permission-denied

I have a site hosted by siteground and my .htaccess file was hacked (I think), Denys all requests. I can acces the files via ftp but I cannot modify or delet the .htaccess file (Operation not permited). The files owneship it's ok, its my username, the acces rights are 644. 
Is there another way to block the file? Why I cannot edit my .htaccess file?
Any idea?

Levente

Comment: why don't you replace your htaccess?or overload all your page instead?

Comment: I can't overwrite the .htaccess file...

Comment: try to backup your actuall project and then replace it with a new copy becuase if you tried to delete or modify and it doesn't work, the only thing i would do is replace my project

Answer (score 0):

try to read this article

https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/troubleshooter/atsubdomains.html

its tittle is **"I created a .htaccess file on my main site and I can't access my other domains on the same account"**